# Assigning a string to private member causes a crash

Tags: c++

So basically I wanted here to assign a string to the first element of the array `Events`, but apparently I'm doing something wrong here.
The crashes occur exactly when assigning a string to the vector `Events`. I minimized the program into one file so that you can reproduce it on your side.

```
class CPerson {
 public:
  CPerson() = default;
  ~CPerson() {}
  friend class CEvent;

 private:
  std::string Name;
};

class CEvent {
 public:
  CEvent() = default;
  void load();
  void add();
  ~CEvent() {}

 private:
  std::string Name;
  std::vector<CEvent *> Events;
  CPerson *Teacher = nullptr;
};

void CEvent::load() {
  Teacher->Name = "test1";  // Crash here
}

void CEvent::add() {
  CEvent *E = new CEvent();
  E->load();
  Events.push_back(E);
}

int main() {
  CEvent a;
  a.add();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Teacher is a pointer which you never initialized, dereferencing it invokes undefined behavior. You will have to modify the constructor to allocate a teacher for that pointer.

Comment: Nowhere in CEvent Teacher is initialized

Comment: you have a pointer to a teacher, but there is no teacher in your code.

Comment: Change `CPerson *Teacher;` to `CPerson *Teacher = nullptr;` and change the `load` routine to do `if (Teacher) Teacher->Name = "test1";`

Comment: Thanks all for the quick replies but it still crashes , even when initializing the '*Teacher' in CEvent

Comment: @Eljay I tried what you wrote too and it still doesn't work

Comment: How did you initialize it?

Comment: Update your question with what you now have. By the way, The CEvent pointers and Teacher pointer will not be deleted on destruction of CEvent. Are you sure you need pointers? If so, I'd recommend either shared or unique pointers.

Comment: You are missing allocation of memory for Teacher. Try putting `Teacher = new CPerson();` in the constructor,

Comment: Yes now it makes sense but I don't need to initialize the CPerson *Teacher to nullptr since the constructor is set to default right ?

Comment: The default constructor would not allocate memory for it, the allocation doesn't have to be in the constructor, it just has to be somewhere before the first use. Initializing it with `nullptr` as suggested doesn't do much here. Note that using `new` both allocates memory and initializes (i.e. calls constructor)

Comment: Yes that's what I thought . Thank you

Comment: You did not update `Teacher->Name = "test1";` to `if (Teacher) Teacher->Name = "test1";`.

Answer (score 0):

from my vision i found tow things who make program crash

> 1 : you want to access private value directly
> 2 : you try to set
> value for nullptr member

to deal with private value in safety you need to make function inside parent class

> example : like getName & SetName function for get & set private value

here is my copy of your code it's **edited** i test it worked finally for me in **VS2019**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

class CPerson {
public:
    CPerson() = default;
    ~CPerson() {}
    friend class CEvent;

    // this function for adding name "because it's a private member" 
    void SetName(std::string Newname) {
        // passing Newname as new value
        this->Name = Newname;
    }

    // this function for getting Name "because it's a private member" 
    std::string getName() {
        // return Name as value
        return this->Name;
    }

private:
    std::string Name;
};

class CEvent {
public:
    CEvent() = default;
    void load();
    void add();
    ~CEvent() {}

    // this function just for showing if teacher name really changed or not
    void ShowTecherName() {
        // we using owner function getName for getting "private name" inside Teacher :)
        std::cout << "NAME : " << this->Teacher->getName() << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::string Name;
    std::vector<CEvent*> Events;
    // here don't forget to make new instance form class don't put nullptr for previous problem 
    CPerson* Teacher = new CPerson();
};

void CEvent::load() {
    // testing set new name 
    this->Teacher->SetName("test");
}

void CEvent::add() {
    CEvent* E = new CEvent();
    E->load();
    Events.push_back(E);
}

int main() {
    // try catch if error happen we need to know error type
    try {
        CEvent a;
        a.add();
        // don't forget to load first :)
        a.load();
        // printing new name :)
        a.ShowTecherName();
    }
    catch (std::exception error) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR : " << error.what() << std::endl;
        throw - 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```